ReactJS Component Constant/Function Not Reflecting State Change
I'm trying to understand why my state value does not update within react constants when they are updated, despite the fact the entire rest of the component file does.
All that I am doing here is calling an endpoint, updating the setCallHistoryDetails state with the response JSON, and then displaying that data in a table.
Everything works fine rendering wise, however whenever I try to call editCall on button click from within one of the table columns, the callHistoryDetails state is its original empty value.
However, I notice that the value DOES update on a hotpatch/re-render (but not hard reload), and then everything works as desired.
It's also hard to wrap my mind about the WHY here, because the fact that editCall can even be called means the callHistoryDetails is no longer in it's starting state and has data to render within the table that holds the button to call the function...
I've tried modifying from a const to a function, utilizing the useCallback hook, and a bunch more ideas, but clearly this comes down to a gap in knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated, code is below:
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { useTable, useSortBy } from "react-table";



const useCustomTable = (columns, data) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({ columns, data }, useSortBy);

  return {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  };
};


const CallHistory = () =>{
    const [callHistoryDetails, setCallHistoryDetails] = useState([]);


      useEffect(()=>{
        if(token && agentId && orgId)fetchCallHistory();
      },[token,agentId,orgId]);



      const callColumns = useMemo(
        () => [
          { 
            Header: "Date", 
            accessor: "time", 
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
              <>
                {formatDate(row.original.time)}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            Header: "Actions",
            accessor: "actions",
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
              <><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil hover-cursor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" onClick={() => {editCall(row.original.id)}}>
  <path d="M12.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-10 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.168.11l-5 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.65-.65l2-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .11-.168zM11.207 2.5 13.5 4.793 14.793 3.5 12.5 1.207zm1.586 3L10.5 3.207 4 9.707V10h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.293zm-9.761 5.175-.106.106-1.528 3.821 3.821-1.528.106-.106A.5.5 0 0 1 5 12.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.468-.325"/>
</svg>
             </>
            ),
          },
        ],
        []
      )


      const {
        getTableProps: getCallTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps: getCallTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups: callHeaderGroups,
        rows: callRows,
        prepareRow: prepareCallRow,
      } = useCustomTable(callColumns, callHistoryDetails);

      const fetchCallHistory = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`https://endpoint.com`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "auth-key": token
            },
          });
          if(response.status === 200){
                setCallHistoryDetails(responseJson.body)
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        }
      }

      const editCall = (cid) => {
        console.log("Should find ", cid); //Properly logs cid
        console.log("Current callHistoryDetails State ", callHistoryDetails) // Logs initial empty state []
        const callToUpdate = callHistoryDetails.find(call => call.id === cid); //Is always undefined as state is empty, I've tried 
        if(callToUpdate){
          setEditCallTempInfo(callToUpdate);
          setShowEditCall(true);
        }
      }



    return (
      <>
       <div className="table-responsive">
            {callHistoryDetails.length > 0 ? (
              <table className="table" {...getCallTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                  {callHeaderGroups.map((callHeaderGroup) => (
                    <tr {...callHeaderGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                      {callHeaderGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                        <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                          {column.render("Header")}
                          <span>{column.isSorted ? (column.isSortedDesc ? " " : " ") : ""}</span>
                        </th>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getCallTableBodyProps()}>
                  {callRows.map((callRow) => {
                    prepareCallRow(callRow);
                    return (
                      <tr {...callRow.getRowProps()}>
                        {callRow.cells.map((callCell, index) => (
                         <td {...callCell.getCellProps()}>
                            {callCell.render("Cell")}
                       </td>
                       
                        ))}
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
               ) : (
                <div className="w-100 m-auto text-center">
                  <h6>No calls found</h6>
                </div>
                 )}
            </div>
      </>
      );
}

export default CallHistory;


const callColumns = useMemo(
  () => [
    // ...
  ],
  [],
);


The empty dependency array here tells react that it should calculate callColumns just once on the first render, and then reuse the result every time thereafter.
Part of the memoized callColumns is this prop:
onClick={() => {editCall(row.original.id)}}

Since this is created on the first render, it's referring to the editCall from the first render, which in turn closes over the callHistoryDetails from the first render, which is an empty array. Setting state does not update local variables from previous renders, so the value in this instance of callHistoryDetails will never change.
To get the components to update, you will either need to include all dependencies in the dependency array, or you can remove the memoization entirely. If you want to keep the memoization, you need to memoize editCall as well, or it will break callColumnns's memoization on every render
const editCall = useCallback(
  (cid) => {
    const callToUpdate = callHistoryDetails.find((call) => call.id === cid);
    if (callToUpdate) {
      setEditCallTempInfo(callToUpdate);
      setShowEditCall(true);
    }
  },
  [callHistoryDetails],
);

const callColumns = useMemo(
  () => [
    // ... same content as before
  ],
  [editCall],
);

